# How to clone git repository up to specific time in all branches?

Tags: git

I'm working on a git project with a lot of branches (~100 branches). I know it is possible to checkout for a specific date, but it works only on one branch, what I need is to clone the whole project up to a specific time (specific commit). Is it possible to do in a straight way, without manually (scripting) rebasing all the branches?

Comment: When you clone a repository, by default, you end up with *the entire history* - all commits for all branches. Your question thus, is entirely unclear.

Comment: I know by default it is all history, but i want entire history up to specific date ignoring everything later (Point in time)

Comment: For what purpose? That's not really how Git works. Are you just trying to look at the log, or what?

Comment: The purpose is straightforward: Git project is repository for students tasks. Every student works on it's own branch (It about 100 of them); Obviously tasks have deadlines. Easiest trick is to checkout project when deadline comes,

Comment: I was wondering is there are some method to work with full project history and all branches at once, without checking history of every branch

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [--shallow-since=<date>](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---shallow-sinceltdategt) with `git clone`. The documentation is not entirely clear about whether it applies to all branch, but I assume so, as e.g. for the related `--depth` it says to imply `--single-branch`, but there is no such note for `--shallow-since`.

Comment: Check out the OP's comments on the question - this seems to be the opposite of his (unclear) desire.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, you explained what you're *actually* trying to do:

> The purpose is straightforward: Git project is repository for students tasks. Every student works on it's own branch (It about 100 of them); Obviously tasks have deadlines. Easiest trick is to checkout project when deadline comes,

I would not use a single repository for this purpose - students could easily overwrite each other's branches, or otherwise falsify commits. This is a recipe for disaster.

Instead,  here's what I would do:

- Set up a private instance of GitLab, and give each student an account
- Create a *group* for the course
- In that group, create a project for each student's submission  (one assignment)
- Grant the student *master* privileges on the group, set to expire on the deadline

In this way, the student will only be able to push to the repository until the deadline.

There are other variations that might also work.

Comment: It is overkill for my use case: firstly everybody shows their tasks and submit report to another system. Locking repository it not solution, there are additional times when can submit late tasks (of course grade going down). Main purpose of big repo to check if nobody brings exactly same problem twice